# how to add the addon adblockplus to firefox profile using webdriver

Tags: selenium

i am using below code for adding the extension adblock plus  to firefox profile

File f = new File("C:\FirefoxProfile\extensions\{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}.xpi");
                                        fp.addExtension(f);

but when i add this, i am getting error unable to find the location.
can any one please answer this .

Answer (score 0):

Your path is not correct.

Correct path would be: `C:\\FirefoxProfile\\extensions\\{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}.xpi`

Java reads `\\` as `\`

```
Check out this simple program:
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
  File myDir = new File("C:\\jdk1.5.0\\src\\java\\io");
System.out.println(myDir);
 }
}
```

The output will be: `C:\jdk1.5.0\src\java\io`

EDIT:

```
public void aaaa() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\FirefoxProfile\\adblock_plus-2.6.6-tb+an+fx+sm"); 
    FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
    fp.addExtension(file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rafal. i had added as u  said still i am getting this error.

Comment: i tried the below one too File file = new File("C:\\FirefoxProfile\\adblock_plus-2.6.6-tb+an+fx+sm");
     fp.addExtension(file);
     fp.setPreference("extensions.AdblockPlus.currentVersion", "2.6.6");     still i am getting error. can we really add aaddon to the  browser opened by the webdriver. because  i couldn't even open firebug with it.please give a solution for this.

Comment: Did you create FirefoxProfile? Check my edited answer.

Comment: According to https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html

it should work. Unless i misunderstood that.

"addExtension(java.io.File extensionToInstall)
Attempt to add an extension to install into this instance." - yes it's possible to install extension to browser.